# Do all android devices have the folder "sdcard"?

Tags: java, android, debugging

I'm creating an application that saves a file inside /mnt/sdcard/.myapp

The folder "/mnt/sdcard" exists on Nexus 5 and G3, does it exist on all devices?

Comment: No. Sometimes it's called differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm creating an application that saves a file inside /mnt/sdcard/.myapp

Please [use `getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) for a location unique for your app. Do not clutter up the user's external storage root.

> The folder "/mnt/sdcard" exists on Nexus 5 and G3, does it exist on all devices?

Not necessarily. If you must work off of the root of external storage, please [use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) to get it.

Comment: Thanks bud, I used `File photo = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic.jpg");` it works, but is it correct?

Comment: @Josh: I would use a file extension (e.g., `pic.jpg`), but otherwise that should be fine.